# Simple logic in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I was programming quietly, but I came across a serious problem he could not solve. I prepared a simple script to exemplify.I have skirted the issue, but wanted an explanation of what's going on.

```
<?php class Test{
public $Dados, $LastDados;
public function Test(){
        $this->Dados = (object) array();
        $this->LastDados = (object) array();

        $this->Dados->Latitude = 111;
        $this->LastDados->Latitude = 333;

        $this->LastDados = $this->Dados;
}
public function Show(){
        $this->Dados->Latitude = 222;
        echo $this->LastDados->Latitude;
}
}
$C = new Test;
$C->Show(); 
?>
```

The result will be '222', but why?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this:

```
$this->LastDados = $this->Dados;
```

which means that `$this->LastDados` is now the same object. So anything you change in `$this->Dados` will also be in `$this->LastDados`.

Try doing this instead and see what happens:

```
$this->LastDados = clone $this->Dados;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I did not know the clone method. I think I need to study more! :)

Comment: In addition to @timhysniu's answer. In PHP _objects_ are passed and assigned **by reference** (like they are linked together), whereas _arrays_ are passed **by value**. When you use `clone` you are basically telling PHP to cut the reference, similar to passing by value. You can try to see what happens if your objects was arrays. You'll see that you don't need to clone them. Remember this for passing objects and arrays to methods/functions. You can specify that an array should be passed by reference as well, just like an object, by writing & infront: `$lastDados = &dados`

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator (=) works with objects in a different way that with variables (in PHP 5): instead of traditional assignment by value behaviour, with object there's a assignment **by reference**, which means that we obtain a sort of alias of the object.

Practically, this code

```
$var1 = 'One';
$var2 = 'Two';
$var1 = $var2;
$var2 = 'Three';
echo "$var1".PHP_EOL;
echo "$var2".PHP_EOL;
```

outputs this:

```
Two
Three
```

because `$var1` maintains previous value of `$var2`, even when you change value of `$var2`.

Whereas adding these lines at and of your code:

```
$C->LastDados->Latitude = 100;
echo $C->Dados->Latitude.PHP_EOL;
echo $C->LastDados->Latitude.PHP_EOL;
```

outputs this:

```
100
100
```

because `$C->Dados` and `$C->LastDados` are - in facts - the **same** object instance.
If you want a copy of an object, you have to use the `clone` keywords:

```
$this->LastDados = clone $this->Dados;
```

You can find more on PHP Documentation: [assignment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [cloning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: I did not know the clone method. You explained very well. Thank you!